# samsung market not working on static ip and static proxy wifi

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab, proxy

I own a android 2.2 based samsung galaxy tab. When i tried connecting through the proxy server on wifi at my office only the browser is able to connect to internet through static ip address, but rest none of the applications were able to connect to internet and this wifi via static ip and proxy settings.

Can some one help ?

Answer (score 3):

Your router in the office is blocking ports - while accepting port 80 for http requests.

Contact your administrator.

I know , at my office , our admin had to change some settings ( but I don't know what ports were necessary ).